# npm ERR! 404 Not Found: require-from-string

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

1. I'm try to install app on **Heroku**.
2. I've set `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` to install `devDepencencies`.
   (I've must install them to build `dist` version of app)
3. Installation always failed with this message:

   ```
   remote: -----> Building dependencies
   remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
   remote:        npm ERR! code E404
   remote:        npm ERR! 404 Not Found: require-from-string@https://registry.npmjs.org/require-from-string/-/require-from-string-1.2.1.tgz
   ```

Comment: Getting the same issue. Works if you add `node_modules` to source and push `git push heroku master`. But this is obviously a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because of "Several Packages Missing from the Registry" (see https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj)

I've got the same error - I think that we just need to wait for status fixed :)